# Finding word/element in list and return matched value

Tags: python, list

I am struggling with the following Problem. I have two lists: `wordList` and `myLIST`

The goal is to check if any of the elements in `wordList` also are in `myList`. Then the matched value should be returned.

The script is the following:

```
import re

myList = ['volkswagen-ag','audi-ag','lamborghini-ag']  
wordList = ['volkswagen','audi','lamborghini'] 


def findWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

    for x in myList:
        b = findWholeWord(y)(x)
        print(b)
```

It produces this result:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='volkswagen'>
None
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='audi'>
None
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='lamborghini'>
```

How can I get the value of the matched field in `myLIST` (For example: `"Volkswagen"` should return `"volkswagen-ag"`? I have just a solution from another blog entry.

I want to create a new list with the matched value.

Answer (score 0):

You are including word boundaries, but you are not including the characters after your search word. You should update your regular expression to `r'\b({0}[^\s]+)\b'`. This will pull any non-space characters after your search words.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great and quick awnser. No iam receiving the right results. One last question. How can i Access the matched value?   
<re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='volkswagen-ag'>
None
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='audi-ag'>
None
[]

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The result is stored in a tuple you can access it by `b[1]`.

Comment: And what can i do if i want to store all matched value in a list?

Comment: This might be a bit more difficult than the question would make it seem. Try rephrasing the question to be instead of "I want to <do this hard thing>" to "I want <to get this result>." Looking thru comments, RE might not be the best way to get what you want.

Comment: The result should be: volkswagen-ag,audi-ag,lamborghini-ag. The only question is how can i extract the matched value from re.MatchObject:   <re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='volkswagen-ag.htm'>
None
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='audi-ag.htm'>
None

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Your desired output is identical to your input, so I can't figure out what you want. It's very difficult to understand what you want the code to do.

Comment: Okay. I've just started learning python and i'am now trying to crawl some web data. I'am using the Pandas Framework to get values from a few tables. The table contains some descriptions in the first columns. In the other columns are the values. That works fine. Then i want to drill into some rows of the table(based on the description text). The Problem is that the displayed text within in the table does not match with the HREFS on the page. For example: In the table there is a data row for "Volkswagen", "Value: 50". But the Hyperlink is: "volkswagen-ag". Thats why iam trying to match them.